# OneNote desktop add-in - where to start?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, onenote

i've spent the last week or so trying to start developing an add-in for the desktop version of microsoft OneNote, but all i've been able to find in terms of documentation are add-ins that seem to run exclusively as task-pane add-ins for the web client. is there something i'm missing? where should i look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly so. Most probably you have created a new web add-in based on the task pane. But web add-ins may include dialogs, ribbon UI customizations and etc. Read more about possible things in the [OneNote add-ins documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/onenote/).

Comment: ahh, thanks- looks like i've just gotta figure out how to use the OneNote REST API now, hahah